# SQL Server The column cannot be processed because more than 1 code page (65001 and 1252) are specified for it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I did a `select *` on a table. I exported the results and tried to import it and write to another table (I have to do this via SSIS, I cannot do this via SQL Server (i.e. `select into`) for security permission purposes, but I can do it this way).

How can I fix this error? What exactly does it mean? I tried searching StackOverflow but my search was not very helpful.

I tried to use an OLEDB source step, but my server instance does not appear for some reason, so now I'm trying to export/import out of SSMS.

Comment: Good day `(1)` What do you mean by "cannot do this via sql server" but using SSIS. SSIS is only a tool that uses SQL Server and there is no way to work directly with SQL Server without a tool since SQL Server has no GUI but set of services. We usually use SQL Server Management Studio Or SQL Operations Studio as a GUI tool in order to execute queries, but these are external tools. Therefore, I suspect you meant to say "not using direct queries" or "Not using SSMS" and not "not using SQL Server". `(2)` Why do you think that SSIS is more secure then direct queries (hint - it is not)?!?

Comment: `(3)` The last comment of the update is not clearto me, please clarify `(4)` Please provide the structureof the tab;e by posting the query that create the table (not image! and not stories about the structure, but simple CREATE query which include all indexes and constraint)

Comment: I do not know this particular message, but this points to conflicting collations. Check your server's default collation, der default collation of your database and the definition of tables / views involved...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I usually get this error while im having a destination and a source with different codepages. it seems that you have a flat file with a 1252 codepage and a destination table with 65001 codepage (or vice versa).
You should try `Data Conversion` component between your source component and destination.

Answer (score 11):

I had same issue. I resolved it setting `AlwaysUseDefaultCodePage` settings as `True`  and setting the `DefaultCodePage` as `65001` (same as source file).

**Note**: Opening the csv file in Notepadd++ and making necessary codepage changes is another option

Screenshots below.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to map a column from a value with `Code Page` **65001** (UTF-8) to a value with **1252** (ANSI - Latin I) or vice versa.
To fix that, I recommend you to include a task of type **Derived Column** and add a new column with the appropriate `Code Page`. Now you must obtain an output with the appropriate encoding to retrieve the data.

[image]